# Repositories for apt-get source in WSL

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking to apt-get the source code of packages in WSL.

```
$ apt-get source bash
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

These are the default sources that came with the installation:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Where do they reside and how should I go on adding them?

Comment: Just to confirm, you can, in fact, add normal Debian repositories to WSL and get a measure of success installing binaries. I wasn't so sure, but it worked for getting `kubectl` via `deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main` as described at https://www.devops.buzz/kubernetes-install-kubectl-on-ubuntu/#Install_using_apt I'm really starting to enjoy switching for Apple's failing hardware [standards] to Windows.

Answer (score 6):

As no one has adequately answered this question and I came here looking for the answer but found it out myself, I figured I'll add it so that others may benefit.

On WSL Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial), the sources reside in `/etc/apt/sources.list` You may edit that directly in your favorite editor and then run `sudo apt update` to see changes.
Note that the sources are included as comments by default, so simply uncommenting them by deleting the `#`  (and adding additional repositories if desired) can be done very simply.

#### Edit:

If for some reason your `sources.list` file is corrupted and/or simply does not have them, you can download the current version of the original source image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current, then find and download the `xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz` file (note the **amd64** and **wsl** parts of the filename). Inside that archive you can find the original file at `etc/apt/sources.list`, which you can use to replace or take from to supplement your current file.

Other newer versions of WSL Ubuntu can also be found at the main https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ address.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add this line :

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you came to this question for the same reason I did:

I had just installed/activated WSL, and I wanted to open Midnight Commander. I typed `mc` and there was no mc. So I did what the system recommended and did `apt install mc` and the system said it had never heard of mc.

I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list` as Shenk advises, and I found plenty of sources! No need to go hunting. All that was missing was

`apt update` .

After that, I could install every software known to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in 2021, the below is not valid anymore.

> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

Use apt-add-repository instead:

```
apt-add-repository http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```